# Disable anchor link after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an anchor link and need behavior in that when the user clicks on it i need it to then disable until the page loads again, at which point its re-enabled again (and then disabled again when user clicks, etc)..

Very same behavior as per a submit post button on a form where it can be disabled until it does the post.

I haven't come across an example yet so hoping someone can help.

I have tried e.PreventDefault on the click event but that prevents the link from being clicked on full stop which i don't want. (i need it to be clicked on and THEN disabled)

Sample code..

```
$(function () {
  $('header.div.nav.ul').first().on("click", function (e) {

        // how do i disable the link?

  });
});
```

HTML sample.. (am trying to target the link with text 'Blah'

```
<header class="module module-header">
  <div class="centered">
    <a href="/Open24Redesign/Accounts/Overview/Index" class="logo logo-small">
      <img src="" data-src="" data-src-retina="" alt="logo" style="opacity: 1;">
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul class="unstyled clearfix">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="">x</a></li>
        <li><a href="">y</a></li>
        <li><a href="">z</a></li>                 
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Many thanks

Comment: You're targeting an UL, and an UL is not a link, nor can it be disabled

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling a anchor with a click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785833/disabling-a-anchor-with-a-click-event)

Comment: sorry wasn't clear - there is an anchor link within the first li element

Comment: @AdrianSean - you're still not targeting that anchor, so adding `preventDefault` or `$(this).prop('disabled', true)` won't work as you're targeting the UL.

Comment: Is it a link that is executing or is it a function that is causing the page to load?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We will create a flag to check if the button has been clicked or not and then if it was clicked we will disable it and if not then it will be clicked

```
 var clicked = false;
 $('header.div.nav.ul li').first().find('a').on("click", function (e) {
    if(clicked===false){
       clicked=true;
    }else{
       e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

as you want click event to be only executed once, You should rather use  `.one()` instead of `.on()`

```
 $('header.div.nav.ul').first().one("click", function (e) {

        // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `one` instead of `on`. You can also simplify your selector a bit:

```
$('header nav a').one('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do what you want the first time here
  // it will only get executed once
});
```

Reference for jquery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 0):

My experiment in Chrome shows that the combination of [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and `e.preventDefault();` is not enough for this purpose. The first time you click the link, it does not use the href, but follows the code in your `.one('click', function(e) { });`. However, if you double-click the anchor tag, it uses the href.

To fix this issue, I would change the anchor tag to a button without href and [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method, or I would use some modification of the proposed code in Muhammad Saleh's answer:

```
var clicked = false;
$('#aTagID').on('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(clicked === false) {
       clicked = true;
       window.location = "..."; // or some other code.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions on this page do not easily allow for multiple links to be setup.

This is a jQuery implementation which works with any element.

Additionally, it will work for any number of links on the same page and is pretty easy to implement.

Choose a class name unlikely to be used.

Just add the class "can_click_once" to any div, anchor, button, etc which you want only to be clicked once.

Insert this Javascript

```
$(".can_click_once").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass( "qubux" )) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('qubux');
        //you can also run other stuff you need once
    }
});
```